# Will an update statement to 0 be generally faster if 0 values are excluded from the update?

Tags: sql, sap-ase

I need to simplify a complex sql statement and I have come a long way, now I would like to remove a condition which seems superfluous to me: making sure that rows which already have the value are not updated.

**Question**: In general, will one of the two update statemens be faster than the other?

Option 1: (simpler)

```
UPDATE example_table SET example_column = 0
WHERE some_conditions
```

Option 2: (with an additional condition not to update elements which are already 0)

```
UPDATE example_table SET example_column = 0 
WHERE some_conditions AND example_column <> 0
```

**Subquestion**: if option 2, why isn't the database optimization able to detect this?

Comment: Second one. (Smaller transaction.)

Comment: You should tell us which database you are using (e.g. SQL Server, Oracle).

Comment: That depends on the database engine and what locking is used. If you lock row-by-row, then the second will almost certainly be faster. If you lock the entire table, then there can be cases where it does not differ that much.

Comment: @TimBiegeleisen I was hoping this would have a db-independent answer.

Comment: @Beginner: but it depends on what engine is used, how queries are optimized executed, how tables/rows are locked,...

Comment: Sub-question answer: The db is not allowed to optimize away updates.

Comment: @jarlh Ok, this means I wrote a lot of inefficient queries in the last years since I always assumed this would be detected by the query optimizer. Thank you for the info, please post as answer.

Comment: You'd better tag the dbms you're using, and let someone who knows that product well write a correct answer. My comments are just general comments.

Comment: And, depending on the situation, sometimes you want set 0 to 0 to be included in the transaction. For example if there are triggers involved.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Option 2 will be at least as fast as Option 1. Depending on the way your database is configured, Option 2 may be faster, especially when the number of rows that have zero represents a significant fraction of rows matching `some_condition`, and your database defines update triggers with expensive logic on `example_table`.

The reason the optimizer cannot optimize Option 1 into Option 2 is that their semantics are not identical. Although both options ultimately leave RDBMS in the same state, all updates must be reported to RDBMS triggers. For Option 1, this includes trivial updates, which are excluded for Option 2.